# mongodb find only specified elements

Tags: mongodb

I have this Schema

```
{
    cc: [
          { user_id: "1", hasSeen:true}
         ,{ user_id: "2", hasSeen:false}
         ,{ user_id: "3", hasSeen:false}

    ]
    ,conversation: [{
        user_id: "1",
        text: "message by 1, to 2and3"
    }]
}
,{
    cc: [
          { user_id: "1", hasSeen:true}
         ,{ user_id: "2", hasSeen:false}
         ,{ user_id: "3", hasSeen:false}
         ,{ user_id: "4", hasSeen:false}
    ]
    ,conversation: [{
        user_id: "1",
        text: "message by 1, to 2,3and4"
    }]
}
```

This is how I set the "inbox" db.
To find the conversations where there is user "1", I use this query:

```
find({ cc:{$elemMatch:{ user_id:"1"}} })
```

and it works great but it gives me back both the results.

now I would like to find the element which has **only** user 1,2and3.
and if I use this query

```
find({ cc:{$elemMatch:{ user_id:"1", user_id:"2", user_id:"3" }} })
```

it gives me back **also** the second element, witch includes also the user 4. (and I don't want to get it).
I mean the last query works as the (sql) "or" operator and I need to use the "and" operator.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved in another way, counting elements!

```
UserInbox.findOne( { 'cc.user_id': { $all: ["1","2","3"] }, cc:{ $size: 3 } } );
```

hope to help someone else :)